# Proof that if a matrix is invertible, its rank is maximum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

I have to prove that if a square matrix $A \in \mathfrak{M}_n (\mathbb{K})$ is invertible, then $rg(A) = n$. The thing is I cannot use vector spaces, subspaces, etc... to prove this, only matrix theory (elemental transformations, operations with matrices, elemental matrices etc...).

I have managed to prove the contrarreciprocal (i.e if $rg(A) < n \implies \nexists A^{-1}$) using a rather complicated argument. Consider the following statements:

1. $A$ is invertible.
2. $BA=0 \implies B=0$.
3. $AB=0 \implies B=0$.
4. $rg(A) = n$.

I proved $(1) \implies (2) \implies (3)$. Then I proved $(2) \implies (4)$ by proving the contrarreciprocal (i.e. $\neg(4) \implies \neg (2)$. This effectively proves $\neg (4) \implies \neg (1)$, if I prove first $\neg(2) \implies \neg(1)$ (which I did), thus $(1) \implies (4)$, which is what I wanted to prove.

For anyone interested, below is my proof (which is mostly irrelevant to my question, you can skip reading it if you want).

### Proof

$(1) \implies (2)$. If $A$ is invertible and $BA=0$, then multiplying by $A^{-1}$ from the right we get $BAA^{-1} = 0A^{-1} \implies BI_n=B=0$.

$(2) \implies (3)$. Similarly, If $A$ is invertible and $AB=0$, then multiplying by $A^{-1}$ from the left we get $A^{-1}AB=A^{-1}0 \implies I_nB=B=0$.

$\neg(4) \implies \neg (2) \implies \neg (1)$. Let's assume that $rg(A)<n$, and let $H_A^f$ be the hermite normal form by rows of $A$. As $rg(A)<n$, the last row of $H_A^f$ will be entirely made up of zeros. Now consider the following square matrix $D \in \mathfrak{M}_n (\mathbb{K})$, which has zeros in all of its entries except in the last one, in which there is a $1$:

$$D=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$$

Obviously, $DH^f_A=0$. Now $H^f_A$ can be expressed as the product of certain elemental matrices, as $H^f_A$ is obtained from $A$ by applying certain elemental row transformations.
So $H^f_A=E_kE_{k-1}...E_2E_1A$, where $E_k,E_{k-1},...,E_2,E_1$ are all elemental matrices. Thus $$0=DH^f_A=D(E_kE_{k-1}...E_2E_1A)=(DE_kE_{k-1}...E_2E_1)A$$
Thus concluding $\neg(2)$, as we have found a matrix $B:=DE_kE_{k-1}...E_2E_1\neq0$ such that $BA=0$ (the reason why $B\neq 0$ is that the product of elemental matrices is invertible, and thus if $D(E_kE_{k-1}...E_2E_1)=0$, we can multiply by $(E_kE_{k-1}...E_2E_1)^{-1}$ from the right, which should yield $D=0$ according to step $(2) \implies (3)$ (which is true and was proven), but is obviously a contradiction because of the way I constructed $D$).

**Question**: is there a (simpler) alternative way to prove this, preferrably a direct proof, that only uses simple tools and concepts like the ones used in my proof (i.e. *matrix theory*)?

Also, can someone confirm the validity of my proof?

Comment: I don't get it: if you can't used vector space and stuff, then how do you **define** rank of a matrix??

Comment: Perhaps the maximum cardinality of a linearly independent set of rows/columns?

Comment: "linearly independent" is vector space stuff, @SamDeHority...yet let us wait until the OP dignifies us addressing my doubt.

Comment: @DonAntonio My definition of [rank of a matrix] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_linear_algebra#Rank_from_row_echelon_forms) is the number of non-null rows of its Hermite normal form by rows. Using matrix transposition you can prove that it is also the number of non-null columns of its Hermite normal form by columns. $rg(A) =$ number of non-null rows of $H^f_A = $ number of non-null columns of $H^C_A$.

Comment: Isn't the Hermite Normal Form defined for *integer* matrices?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yeah, apparently [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form) also gives that definition, but I don't fully agree with it. What I understand by Hermite normal form by rows is what over the Atlantic most people refer to as the reduced row echelon form. Anyhow, I am not referring exclusively to integer matrices, but to all square matrices that have in their entries elements of a given field $\mathbb{K}$.

Comment: Well, if I understand your point then the exercise is almost trivial: if $\;rk(A)<n\;$ then, upon reducing the matrix by rows, you get *at least* one row all of which entries are zero, and since the reduced matrix in invertible iff the original one is, we're done. In the last part, if you're allowed to, you can use a determinant argument.

Comment: @DonAntonio *"since the reduced matrix is invertible iff the original one is"*. You'd have to formally prove this, which is not trivial, and that a matrix with a null row is not invertible, which  is *almost* trivial. I suppose proofs with determinants are OK; can you please be more specific or direct me to a specific proof?

Comment: Of course it is not trivial (though it is not hard, either), yet you said using matrix theory, so I'm assuming basic, elementary stuff like this is known...The determinant thing is basic: the reduced matrix and the original one have the same determinant up to a non -zero constant (in case some row was multiplied by such), and assuming (again!) the basic properties of determinants, a matrix with a zeros row has zero determinant and thus isn't invertible...etc.